# Laravel | Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When I try to make url like that which have an id this problem occur

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
Route::get('/doctor/{doctorId}', [App\Http\Controllers\DoctorController::class, 'services'])->name('doctor.profile');
```

if i view the page from other url which have no id it work i know that's strange and i have no idea why !!!

Comment: what actual URL are you hitting? what does your method's signature look like, what are you doing in the method? is this route actually registered?

Comment: @lagbox i created page for doctors when i click to the name of this doctor this page open and it is contain of the services of this doctor

this code which i have written in controller page

 public function services($doctorId)
    {
        $doctor = Doctor::find($doctorId);
        $services = $doctor -> services;

        $doctors = Doctor::select('id', 'name')->get();
        $allservices = Service::select('id', 'name');
        return view('services', compact('services', 'doctors', 'allservices'));
    }

Comment: When i deleted id from url and id parameter from controller it works it's strange ... but i want to write id :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will generate Method, URI, and Action Class did you registered.

```
php artisan route:list --compact
```

If you have not found your URI `'/doctor/{doctorId}'`, then enter this

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: the problem is it assumed when i write this url that there is a folder called doctor in public folder in the project 
`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

but the folder of css is not in doctor folder so i tried to write the whole url 
this error appear "Not allowed to load local resource"

but it work that's strange
    `<link href=" http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Answer (score 0):

A 404 message is usually displayed if the model can't be found.

```php
$model = SomeModel::find(doctorId)

dd($model)
```

result in the dd = null / hense the error.